# How to make custom key type auto repeat in xkb

Tags: xkb, autorepeat

I have defined a custom key type in my xkb configure file to do some redirection (e.g. redirect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to <kbd>Up</kbd> etc.) However, I cannot get auto-repeat work for this custom type (neither the original key (e.g. <kbd>p</kbd>) or the redirect action (e.g. <kbd>Up</kbd> redirected from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) has auto-repeat).

I have tried adding `repeat=true,` to `keysyms` configuration according to [this from xfree86 mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/xfree86.internationalization/2004-04/msg00011.html) but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Please, read `man xset` for the `r` option. It is possible to enable autorepeat for a particular key by providing its integer code to the `xset r` command. For example:

I have

```
<SPCE> = 134;
```

in my custom xkbcom keymap file. So, issuing:

```
xset r 134
```

in the terminial, will enable autorepeat for my remapped Space key.

You might add this command to your `~/.xinitrc` file. No need to tinker with the xkb configure file itself.

Answer (score 2):

There was a patch I stumbled onto within the Chromium OS repository that might help with this; it seems to have been removed after they actually patched it into Chrome itself.  Not sure what happened with the QA for the patch or if it was sent upstream or not.

links here: [X: Map Alt-Up and Alt-Down to Page Up and Page Down](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/overlays/chromiumos-overlay.git;a=blob;f=x11-base/xorg-server/files/1.7.6-fix-xkb-autorepeat.patch;h=8bad5abc5ad3958f6d73c55c67d3883ac775db18;hb=c3ce41719abc82a257e1fef1c499ea2e7c6b3c32)

The patch is as follows:

```
This is a probably-wrong fix for an issue where autorepeat
is disabled for keys assigned by XKB.  As far as I can tell,
XKB has the correct autorepeat settings for the keys before
a completely-empty autorepeat array from X is copied over
it; then the XKB array is copied back to X.  This makes us
skip the first copy.

diff --git a/xkb/xkbUtils.c b/xkb/xkbUtils.c
index 75e243c..bceb55c 100644
--- a/xkb/xkbUtils.c
+++ b/xkb/xkbUtils.c
@@ -342,9 +342,6 @@ CARD8 *         repeat;
     xkb= xkbi->desc;
     repeat= xkb->ctrls->per_key_repeat;

-    if (pXDev->kbdfeed)
-   memcpy(repeat,pXDev->kbdfeed->ctrl.autoRepeats,32);
-
     XkbUpdateDescActions(xkb,first,num,changes);

     if ((pXDev->kbdfeed)&&
```

I've yet to try it myself, but will probably take a shot at it in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue where I redirected <kbd>SUPER + H</kbd> to <kbd>LEFT</kbd> which worked, but didn't repeat.

It worked when I added `autorepeat = yes` to the key symbol definition.

Found it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20190320180541/http://pascal.tsu.ru/en/xkb/gram-symbols.html

Comment: Could you post an example for this setting, the linked pages does no longer exist.